# Obtain Kerberos ticket automatically (on boot) in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, kerberos, ansible

I'm using Ansible to administer a group of Windows servers, with my control machine running CentOS 7.1. I've set up my /etc/krb5.conf file to authenticate to a domain controller so I can use one domain account to authenticate to all of my hosts. This works fine - as long as I manually run `kinit user@DOMAIN.COM` first.

The problem is, as soon as I reboot my control machine, the Kerberos ticket expires, and any attempt to run Ansible against the Windows servers results in the standard "no Kerberos credentials" error, until I run `kinit` again.

Is there a recommended practice for either:

1. Persisting Kerberos tickets in the event of a system reboot
2. Authenticating against a specific domain on boot?

EDIT: here's my (modified) output to `realm discover`:

```
[root@server ~]# realm discover
my.domain.com
type: kerberos
  realm-name: MY.DOMAIN.COM
  domain-name: my.domain.com
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: oddjob
  required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common
  login-formats: %U@my.domain.com
  login-policy: allow-realm-logins
```

Comment: You should automatically get a ticket when you log in, if the system is properly joined to the domain (which it sounds like it is not). Try [joining it properly to the domain](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/realmd-domain.html) and then try again.

Comment: Did you log in with a local user account or a domain user account? If a local user account, then you'll always have to run `kinit` manually.

Comment: I'm using a domain account to login - so I shouldn't need to touch `kinit`